# convert json into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this json data:

```
{
  "current": [
    [
      0,
      "2017-01-15T00:08:36Z"
    ],
    [
      0,
      "2017-01-15T00:18:36Z"
    ]
  ],
  "voltage": [
    [
      12.891309987,
      "2017-01-15T00:08:36Z"
    ],
    [
      12.8952162966,
      "2017-01-15T00:18:36Z"
    ]
  ]
}
```

and I am trying to get into it into a pandas dataframe in this format (time series):

```
time                  current      voltage
2017-01-15T00:08:36Z    0         12.891309987
2017-01-15T00:18:36Z    0         12.8952162966
```

I have tried:

```
t = pd.read_json(q)
```

but this gives me:

```
                     current                                voltage
0  [0, 2017-01-15T00:08:36Z]   [12.891309987, 2017-01-15T00:08:36Z]
1  [0, 2017-01-15T00:18:36Z]  [12.8952162966, 2017-01-15T00:18:36Z]
```

how can I get this into the correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the columns time is same, aftering reading json we can select the values and concat them :

```
ndf = pd.read_json(q)

ndf = pd.concat([ndf.apply(lambda x : x.str[0]),ndf['current'].str[1].rename('time')],1)

   current    voltage                  time
0        0  12.891310  2017-01-15T00:08:36Z
1        0  12.895216  2017-01-15T00:18:36Z
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how do a set the `time` column as the index, as in the original post? I've tried: `ndf.set_index('time').reset_index()`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why are you resetting ? Just `ndf.set_index('time')` is enough

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is not option in read_json() to do that. My suggestion would be to re-work the table once you read the data.

```
 t = pd.read_json('data.json')
 t['time'] = [x[1] for x in t['current']]
 t['current'] = [x[0] for x in t['current']]
 t['voltage'] = [x[0] for x in t['voltage']]
```